# Use of consteval function parameters in a static_assert

Tags: c++, c++20

My understanding was that [the parameters of consteval functions can't be used in `static_assert`s because they are not considered constant expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226797/will-consteval-allow-using-static-assert-on-function-arguments). However, that only seems to be the case sometimes:

```
// using gcc 13.1 with -std=c++20

#include <array>
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

template<std::ranges::input_range T, std::integral U>
consteval int assertStuff2(T ok, U not_ok) {
    // (1) both compile fine
    static_assert(std::ranges::size(ok) != 5);
    static_assert(ok.size() != 5);
    
    // (2) compiler error!
    // "non-constant condition for static assertion:
    //    'not_ok' is not a constant expression"
    static_assert(not_ok != 5);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << assertStuff2(std::array<int, 3>{5, 3, 2}, 2);
}
```

Why is `ok` usable in a `static_assert` but `not_ok` isn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is `ok` usable in a `static_assert` but `not_ok` isn't?

`ok`, like `not_ok`, is not a constant expression, so you can't do `static_assert(ok != std::array<int, 3>{})` either.

However, `ok.size()` is still usable in `static_assert`, because `ok` is not a reference type, and its `size()` is a `constexpr` function that returns the template parameter `N`, which makes the whole expression can be treated as a constant expression ([[expr.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5)).

`ranges::size(t)` ultimately returns `t.size()`, so it is also a constant expression.

Comment: What might be informative is the fact those static asserts also work in mere `constexpr` functions.  The `consteval` part didn't permit more `static_assert` usage here.