Returning an array from a consteval function where size of an array is a function argument
Why is it not possible to create an array in a consteval function (and return it) if array size is not a function template argument but just a function argument? The argument must be known at compile time, so I would expect the following code to compile:
#include <array>

consteval auto create_array(std::size_t len)
{
     std::array<int, len> arr{42};
     return arr;
}

int main()
{
    static constinit auto arr = create_array(10);
}

On the other hand, this code compiles just fine, which adds to the confusion:
#include <array>

consteval auto get_len(std::size_t len)
{
     return len;
}

int main()
{
    static constinit std::array<int, get_len(10)> arr{42};
}

I'm using GCC 14.1.1 and compiling with -std=c++23.
This answer says constexpr functions cannot do it because they can be called in run time and compile time. But, consteval functions must be called during compile time so values of all arguments are known at compile time.

Do you have to pass the size as an argument? Can't you do it as a template? Like template<std::size_t LEN> consteval auto create_array() { return std::array<int, LEN>{ 42 }; }?

A possibly better dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57226797/3966456. Read the answers in detail and don't focus on the superficial difference in the question.

@WeijunZhou Thanks! This is the correct answer along with the linked paper. If you want, you can create a proper answer and I'll accept it. I wouldn't delete my question as it's hard to relate it to the dupe target you suggest - it wasn't in the related questions when I was creating the question and even the other suggested dupe does not really answer my question.

@Someprogrammerdude I could, but my question is why I can't do it without creating a template function - only with consteval functions.
